# Why do we use relative velocity when describing flow rate of exhaust gases leaving a nozzle?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, reference-frames, velocity, rocket-science

Why do we take the relative velocity instead of the absolute velocity in the analysis of flow rates?  More particularly when we write down momentum, isn't the 'velocity' term which we multiply with the mass, the absolute velocity of the body with respect to some inertial frame?

I am aware that we could shift between different frames but if we are an observer outside, we should take the relative velocity of the exhaust mass

---

[Reference](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Map%3A_University_Physics_I_-_Mechanics%2C_Sound%2C_Oscillations%2C_and_Waves_(OpenStax)/09%3A_Linear_Momentum_and_Collisions/9.11%3A_Rocket_Propulsion)

Answer (score 3):

Because the relative velocity can usually assumed to be approximately constant, which makes things like the [Tsiolkovsky rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) a lot easier to derive (indeed the rocket equation as usually described *assumes* a constant relative velocity of the exhaust).

And, of course, the relative velocity of the exhaust *is* the absolute velocity measured with respect to some inertial frame: the inertial frame in which the rocket is momentarily at rest.